# ¿Cómo puedo usar threading pero cambiando un usuario en Pyhon?

Tags: python, hilos

estoy desarrollando un bot en Python, para subir una misma foto en varias cuentas a la vez, es totalmente whitehat, solo estoy automatizando un proceso.
Estoy usando la libreria threading.

```
from instabot import Bot
import threading
from time import sleep

bot = Bot()

def upload_photo():
    username = "USERNAME"
    password = "PASSWORD"

    bot.login(username=username, password=password)

    bot.upload_photo("image.jpg", caption="My first photo")

threads = list()

for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=upload_photo)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Tengo un archivo de texto en el que tengo todas las cuentas, separadas por un `:`, no tengo problema en dividirlo y almacenarlo en variables, mi problema es, ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el usuario y la contraseña en cada thread?

Comment: Puedes modificar la fx `upload_photo` para que reciba password y username y luego `Thread(target=upload_photo, args=(password,username,)) `

Comment: @LucasDamian de acuerdo, y ahora como cambio el usuario y contraseña cada vez que realice una accion?

Comment: Lo ideal sería tener una lista con las credenciales de usuarios, te propondré una solución con `concurrent.futures`

Comment: @LucasDamian si, como comenté en la publicación, tengo una lista con todos los usuarios. Separando el usuario y contraseña por `:`

Comment: El  formato es:  `foo = [['usuario1:contraseña1'],['usuario2:contraseña2']]` ?

Comment: @LucasDamian el formato es 
usuario:contraseña
usuario:contraseña
Pero uno debajo de otro

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108633/discussion-between-quique-fernandez-and-lucas-damian).